# Creating your own vertex element in XNA

Tags: xna

I needed to create my own VertexElement with the follow - Position, Color & Normal. I found a tutorial explaining how to do this here (http://www.riemers.net/eng/Tutorials/XNA/Csharp/Series1/Terrain_lighting.php).

I created a struct similar to the tutorial and then replaced all the declarations with the new one, but I get this error:

> There is no boxing conversion from 'VertexPositionColorNormal' to
>   'Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Graphics.IVertexType'.

and I get it under the rendering line here:

```
graphicsDevice.DrawUserIndexedPrimitives<VertexPositionColorNormal>
(PrimitiveType.LineList, currentPlayer.LLObject.Vertices, 0, 
    currentPlayer.LLObject.TotalVertices, currentPlayer.LLObject.LinelistIndexes, 0, 
    currentPlayer.LLObject.TotalLinelistIndexes / 2);
```

I had a look on Google to see if there was any obvious answers but it's hard to search for. Could someone spread some light on what is going wrong?

Answer (score 2):

That error indicates that XNA expect your custom vertex type to implement `IVertexType` as shown [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb976065.aspx). Otherwise you need to use the overload that accepts an explicit `VertexDeclaration` object.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: I agree with @anko, this could have been a comment.  But, you clearly knew the nature of the error message and hit it on the head.  You should rephrase it to a statement and maybe add a bit of explanation.  Your answer is correct, you might as well make it as high-quality as you can.

Comment: Thanks I've improved the answer. I would have wrote that as a comment but I had less than 50 pts so I wasn't able to.